# Git Fetch returns 'fatal: I don't handle protocol https' in windows

Tags: windows, git, github, git-fetch

Just after adding remote repo, I tried `git fetch remoteRepoName` but it's returning this error:

`fatal: I don't handle protocol 'https'`

I explored relevant questions but most of these belongs to `git clone` so their answers aren't working in my case. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I can see extra spaces between forkgeek and https://... online 3.

Run these commands to fix it.

```
git remote remove forkgeek

git remote add upstream https://github.com/forkgeeks/aws-cloudwatch-keen-integration.git

git fetch upstream
```

I have changed forkgeek into upstream, you can have whatever name you want.

Answer (score 7):

```sh
git config --local -e
```

This will open up the config file for the repo in Vim where you can delete the extra/special characters that cause this error.

Answer (score 5):

if you have problems after run

```
git push origin master
fatal: I don't handle protocol 'https'
```

Fix it removing that reference

```
git remote rm origin
#then check is all worked well
git remote -v
```

Now you could add again the url for the remote repository

```
git remote add origin https://example.com/user/repo.git
#and check
git remote -v
#And push the changes in your local repository to github
git push origin master
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue could be with the invalid origin URL.

To check repo URL execute below command

```
git remote -v
```

it will show the origin urls and then change with correct url. The below is the command for that.

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/**USERNAME/REPOSITORY**.git
```

again verify with the command

```
git remote -v
```

for more information refer this link

https://help.github.com/articles/changing-a-remote-s-url/

Answer (score 1):

I am new to git and I had a similar problem just now, the reason was that I tried to paste the link to my GitHub repository in the git bash using ctrl+V (I'm on windows) ad then ctrl+shift+v and when it didn't work I just wrote the link manually and when I ran the command it told me I don't handle https, and that's because ctrl+v was the special character they are speaking about in the answers above, so I restarted the bash and just typed in the link manually from the start and it worked, hope it helps.

Comment: As someone coming from Linux and trying to set up a command line workflow in windows, your comment is a treasure. Thanks.

Comment: You're most welcome

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global http.sslVerify false`

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue come up before but it was an easy fix, I had a space before my "https". Fixed that and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Error is because of trailing space in your forgeek url, you can resolve it as

```
git pull https://github.com/forkgeeks/aws-cloudwatch-keen-integration.git master
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I do ctrl + v the right click and past the link,
when I tried again just with the right click and past it works

Comment: just for information: ctrl+insert and shift+insert on bash does the same task as ctrl+c and ctrl+v on windows.