# fatal: I don't handle protocol 'https'

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push some of my files from staging area to my repository.

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/my_name/filename.git
git push -u origin master
fatal: I don't handle protocol 'https'
```

I am getting this fatal error.

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

There is a good chance you have special characters somewhere in your commands according to these two SO posts:

[git: fatal: I don't handle protocol '​​http'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30474447/git-fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol-http)

[Git Fetch returns 'fatal: I don't handle protocol https' in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807697/git-fetch-returns-fatal-i-dont-handle-protocol-https-in-windows)

Retype the commands and the problem should be alleviated.

Comment: there was a space before my https://